# One-point compactification of the union of circle and an intersecting open interval.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I have to give the one-point compactification of $S^1 \cup \{(0,2) \times \{0\}\}$. I think I can see this as a circle with two 'tails' with open ends, one on the inside, one on the outside. Is this homeomorphic to a circle with two 'tails' with open ends on the outside (starting from the same point)? If so, am I correct that it's one-point compactification is a bouquet of two circles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this seems like a reasonable approach to this problem and is probably how I would tackle it. Of course, you need to give a proof of this statement. You first need to show that the space $X$ is locally compact, Hausdorff and non-compact - all very easy to show. You then need to show that the obvious map from $X$ to the wedge of two circles is continuous, open, injective, and the image of the map has the complement of a single point. You also need to show that the wedge of two circles is compact. This shows that the wedge of two circle is then the Alexandroff one-point compactification of $X$.

Comment: Thanks! I know how to do all this, especially because $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. With proving the local compactness I can only think of defining compact neighborhoods for every $x$ of $X$ since $X$ is not open or closed. Is this the only way to do that?

Comment: @user123956 Just use the fact that a subspace $X$ of the locally compact space $Y$ is itself locally compact if and only if $X=A\setminus B$ for two closed subspace $A$ and $B$ of $X$. Just add the points $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ to the space in your question to get the $Y$ you should be working with.